# Sqlite ambiguous column name in Android why none solution is not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I get a Sqlite ambiguous column name on a column named games._id in a rather complicated select query like the following:

```
public Cursor getStatsByResult(String result)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String buildSQL = "SELECT games._id AS game, games.lge, games.date, games.opp, games.ven, games.scr, " +
            "SUM(CASE WHEN s_event = \"1on1\" THEN s_att END) ||\"/\"||"+
            "SUM(CASE WHEN s_event = \"1on1\" THEN s_point END) AS \"1 On 1 \","+
            "SUM(CASE WHEN s_event = \"MyDef\" THEN s_att END) ||\"/\"|| "+
            "SUM(CASE WHEN s_event = \"MyDef\" THEN s_point END) AS \"Switching Def\","+
            "SUM(CASE WHEN s_event = \"Defl\" THEN s_point END) AS Deflections "+
            "FROM records "+
            "INNER JOIN myplayers ON myplayers_id = s_myplayersid "+
            "INNER JOIN games ON games._id = myplayers_gameid "+
            "INNER JOIN games ON sessions.sessions_id = games.sessions_id AND games._id = myplayers.myplayers_game_id "+
            "WHERE games.result=\""+result+"\" AND games.date BETWEEN sessions.sessions_start AND sessions.sessions_end GROUP BY "+
            "games.date,games.rslt,games.opp";

    return db.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);

}
```

Why it is still says this message even if I put games._id and not simply _id?

Comment: The Java code is not interesting. Show the actual SQL, and the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have tried alias name and the problem is with the alias name. I think so.

```
String buildSQL = "SELECT games._id , games.lge, games.date, games.opp, games.ven, games.scr, " +
            "SUM(CASE WHEN s_event = \"1on1\" THEN s_att END) ||\"/\"||"+
            "SUM(CASE WHEN s_event = \"1on1\" THEN s_point END) AS \"1 On 1 \","+
            "SUM(CASE WHEN s_event = \"MyDef\" THEN s_att END) ||\"/\"|| "+
            "SUM(CASE WHEN s_event = \"MyDef\" THEN s_point END) AS \"Switching Def\","+
            "SUM(CASE WHEN s_event = \"Defl\" THEN s_point END) AS Deflections "+
            "FROM records game"+
            "INNER JOIN myplayers ON myplayers_id = s_myplayersid "+
            "INNER JOIN games ON games._id = myplayers_gameid "+
            "INNER JOIN games ON sessions.sessions_id = games.sessions_id AND games._id = myplayers.myplayers_game_id "+
            "WHERE games.result=\""+result+"\" AND games.date BETWEEN sessions.sessions_start AND sessions.sessions_end GROUP BY "+
            "games.date,games.rslt,games.opp";
```

Hope this query solves your issue.